# osmosis schema, style with OSM-Bright

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, osmosis

I have used Osmosis to load a large cut of OSM into a PostGIS DB, that works great. BUT, I would like to use the OSM-Bright style (carto CSS) to style it in TileMill and built tiles, offline. Going through the OSM-Bright user guide/install etc. there is no option to configure it to use an Osmosis schema (only osm2pgsql and imposm).

On windows osm2pgsql will not import very large OSM datasets hence the Osmosis route to get me this far.

Is there a way to style my data imported with Osmosis, or modify my DB so it is in the correct schema (the schema osm2pgsql uses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Osmosis stores the OSM data in the same way as the editor uses it: nodes, ways and relations.

One of the time consuming tasks of osm2pgsql is to convert closed ways and multipolygon relations to multipolygons that can be used for rendering, as well as defining a rendering order of features that overlap like bridges over ways or other buildings. This is not done by osmosis, and doing that manually will be quite a pain.

What you can do:

- Cut the large OSM dataset with osmfilter or osmconvert in smaller, overlapping rectangles, and render those one after each other
- install Oracle virtual box with a current Ubuntu, and render the tiles inside the virtual box

Comment: Great points. To clarify, if i did it on Ubuntu, could i then use osm2pgsql. Is there no way to have osm2pgsql act on the data i have in the DB currently...or is the pointless?

Comment: The data already inserted with osmosis is useless for rendering. I'm not sure where the limit is for osm2pgsql on windows. I have recently imported a 465MB pbf file successfully. For ubuntu, there is no limitation reported.

Comment: Great answer. I'll change my process and report back anything interesting

Comment: Windows does not have any limitations as well. For a fairly new version of osm2pgsql have a look at https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/17

Comment: @Benjamin "if you try to use the planet-latest.osm.pbf it crash" does not look promising...

Comment: There is a version somewhere in the issue that works fine. Also its under active development since osm2pgsql switched from C to C++. I imported the Germany OSM with the default.style on Windows without problems. But this was some time ago.